# Installing mcrypt on Mac OSX (10.5) from PHP 5.2.8 source fails tests, what do I do?

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

So I'm trying to install mcrypt on my local for development. I've never compiled from source before, so please bear with me, but the short of what I've done is:

1. Download and install libmcrypt-2.5.8 (from source)
2. Download compiled mcrypt.so from http://www.viames.it/mac-os-x.html (note: the compiled gd.so seems to work fine)
3. Update php.ini (to include relevant lines)
4. Restart web sharing (apache); pages can't be loaded
5. Remove extension=mcrypt.so line and restart apache, pages load again)
6. Download PHP 5.2.8 source from php.net, and try to configure and install mcrypt from /ext/mcrypt

At this point, when I run make test, things fail.

```
Number of tests :   36                36
Tests skipped   :    0 (  0.0%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   36 (100.0%) (100.0%)
Expected fail   :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests passed    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
```

Just in case anyway, I went ahead and did sudo make install, update php.ini, and tried to load pages. Pages loaded fine. I went to my phpinfo page, but mcrypt isn't shown there at all. I went back and forth on this a couple of times, but nothing happened still.

I'm confused about what to do now, as I'm not sure what I was supposed to do when the make tests failed, which is, I suspect, why my mcrypt isn't working at all (even if the .so file is there). I'm including the make test failed summary result below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test for blowfish compatibility [tests/blowfish.phpt]
Bug #35496 (Crash in mcrypt_generic()/mdecrypt_generic() without proper init). [tests/bug35496.phpt]
Bug #37595 (mcrypt_generic calculates data length in wrong way) [tests/bug37595.phpt]
Bug #41252 (Calling mcrypt_generic without first calling mcrypt_generic_init crashes) [tests/bug41252.phpt]
Bug #46010 (warnings incorrectly generated for iv in ecb mode) [tests/bug46010.phpt]
Bug #8040 (MCRYPT_MODE_* do not seem to exist) [tests/bug8040.phpt]
mcrypt_cbc [tests/mcrypt_cbc.phpt]
mcrypt_cbf [tests/mcrypt_cbf.phpt]
mcrypt_create_iv [tests/mcrypt_create_iv.phpt]
mcrypt_decrypt [tests/mcrypt_decrypt.phpt]
mcrypt_ecb [tests/mcrypt_ecb.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_algorithms_name [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_algorithms_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_block_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_key_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_modes_name [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_mode_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_supported_key_sizes [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_supported_key_sizes.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm_mode [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_mode [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_self_test [tests/mcrypt_enc_self_test.phpt]
mcrypt_get_block_size [tests/mcrypt_get_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_get_cipher_name [tests/mcrypt_get_cipher_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size [tests/mcrypt_get_iv_size.phpt]
mcrypt_get_key_size [tests/mcrypt_get_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_list_algorithms [tests/mcrypt_list_algorithms.phpt]
mcrypt_list_modes [tests/mcrypt_list_modes.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_algo_block_size [tests/mcrypt_module_get_algo_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size [tests/mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_supported_key_sizes [tests/mcrypt_module_get_supported_key_sizes.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm_mode [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_mode [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_module_open [tests/mcrypt_module_open.phpt]
mcrypt_module_self_test [tests/mcrypt_module_self_test.phpt]
mcrypt_ofb [tests/mcrypt_ofb.phpt]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcode via the AppStore

Install MacPorts (http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports)

Install libmcrypt using port

```
port install libmcrypt
```

Download PHP source (http://php.net/downloads.php)

Compile the extension before installing it

```
cd /directory/to/php/source/ext/mcrypt
phpize .
./configure \
--with-php-config=`which php-config` \
--with-mcrypt=/opt/local
make 
sudo make install
```